# How to create a video playlist in reactjs, using html5 video tag?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import "./Video.css";

export class Video extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            index: 1,
            videos: []
        }
        this.numbers = 5;
        for (var i = 1; i < this.numbers + 1; i++) {
            this.setState({
                videos: this.state.videos.push('Video/v' + i + '.mp4')
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='vid ml-5'>
                <video className='video px-2 py-2' autoPlay width='950px' height='auto' src='Video/v1.mp4' ></video>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Video
```

Above is the code for my reactjs video player component I want to create playlist for the urls in the this.state.videos.
Any one can help me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import "./Video.css";

export class Video extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            index: 1,
            videos: []
        }
        this.numbers = 5;
    }

    looping(event) {
        if( this.state.index === this.numbers){
            this.setState({
                index : 1
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                index : this.state.index + 1
            })
        }
        event.target.src = `Video/v${this.state.index}.mp4`
        event.target.play();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='vid ml-5'>
                <video className='video px-2 py-2' autoPlay width='950px' height='auto' src='Video/v1.mp4' onEnded = {(event) => this.looping(event)} ></video>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Video
```

I just removed this.state.video url and track array elements using this.numbers.
I just added a looping function, in which it will loop over array to give a sense of playlist.
Reactjs supports onEnded event for video tag